# How do I return results while using operator overloading +

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I have the code that confused me when I'm using operator overloading and returning the temp object it calls my copy constructor and I'm getting exception but when I'm returning my class member temp.size it calls my parameterized constructor MyClass(int size) and everything works fine. I'm interested in how it works and what it's related to. Code below.

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int* data;
    int size;
    
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        size = 0;
    }
    MyClass(int size)
    {
        this->size = size;
        data = new int[size];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            data[i] = rand();
        }
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass& obj)
    {
        this->size = obj.size;
        this->data = new int[size];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            data[i] = obj.data[i];
        }
    }
    MyClass operator+(const MyClass& obj)
    {
        MyClass temp;
        temp.size = this->size + obj.size;
        return temp.size;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, MyClass& obj);

    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete[]data;
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, MyClass & obj)
{
    os << obj.size;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass a(5);
    MyClass b(a);
    MyClass c = a + b;
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They state at the start of the question that that causes them an exception. It does not cause me an exception when I run it though. I get the opposite. I get no exception with copy constructor, but DO get an exception with the size constructor.

Comment: It causes a crash on destruction of the temp MyClass, because the default constructor does not `new` the data, but does `delete` it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You should set `data` to `nullptr` on the default constructor, then check it is not `nullptr` before deleting it in the destructor.

Comment: This is all assuming you are not allowed to use `std::vector`, because if you are then you should use it because then you do not need to worry about any of this stuff

Comment: Yes I see. But when I'm returning temp (not temp.size) this calls copy constructor and I'm getting exception during ( data[i] = obj.data[i]; ) assignment .How can I fix this?

Comment: `obj.data` does not exist because you do not call `new`

Comment: You are currently setting the variable size, then returning an object with size set but no data created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several issues with your code:

- your default constructor is not initializing `data`.
- your `operator+` is not attempting to copy values from `this->data` and `obj.data` into `temp.data`, thus leaving `temp.data` uninitialized.
- your `operator+` is returning the wrong `MyClass` object.  It goes to the trouble of preparing a `MyClass` object named `temp`, and then completely discards `temp` upon exit.  By passing `temp.size` to `return`, you are creating *another* `MyClass` object via your `MyClass(int size)` constructor, which generates all new random data.  You need to instead `return` the `temp` object that you prepared.  Then the compiler will either call your copy constructor to assign `temp` to `c` in `main()`, or it will [optimize away the copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) to let `operator+` operate directly on `c`.
- you are missing a copy assignment operator, per the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  Nothing in your example actually invokes a copy assignment, but you need to implement the operator properly nonetheless.  And if you are using C++11 or later, you should also follow the [Rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) as well, by adding a move constructor and a move assignment operator.  However, if you can change your design to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`, then you can follow the [Rule of 0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and let the compiler do all the hard work for you.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility> // C++11 and later only...
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>    

class MyClass
{
private:
    int* data;
    size_t size;
    
public:
    MyClass(size_t size = 0) : data(NULL), size(size)
    {
        if (size > 0)
        {
            data = new int[size];
            // in C++11 and later, consider using std::uniform_int_distribution instead of rand()!
            std::generate(data, data + size, std::rand);
        }
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass& obj) : data(NULL), size(obj.size)
    {
        if (size > 0)
        {
            data = new int[size];
            std::copy(obj.data, obj.data + obj.size, data);
        }
    }

    // C++11 and later only...
    MyClass(MyClass&& obj) : data(NULL), size(0)
    {
        std::swap(size, obj.size);
        std::swap(data, obj.data);
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }

    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
        {
            MyClass temp(rhs);
            std::swap(size, temp.size);
            std::swap(data, temp.data);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& rhs)
    {
        MyClass temp(std::move(rhs));
        std::swap(size, temp.size);
        std::swap(data, temp.data);
        return *this;
    }

    MyClass operator+(const MyClass& obj) const
    {
        MyClass temp;
        temp.size = size + obj.size;
        if (temp.size > 0)
        {
            temp.data = new int[temp.size];
            std::copy(data, data + size, temp.data);
            std::copy(obj.data, obj.data + obj.size, temp.data + size);
        }
        return temp;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyClass& obj);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyClass& obj)
{
    os << obj.size;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < obj.size; ++i)
    {
        os << " " << obj.data[i];
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    MyClass a(5);
    MyClass b(a);
    MyClass c = a + b;
    std::cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Which can be simplified to this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

class MyClass
{
private:
    std::vector<int> data;
    
public:
    MyClass(size_t size = 0) : data(size)
    {
        std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), std::rand);
    }

    MyClass operator+(const MyClass& obj) const
    {
        MyClass temp;
        if (!data.empty() || !obj.data.empty())
        {
            temp.data.reserve(data.size() + obj.data.size());
            temp.data.insert(temp.data.end(), data.begin(), data.end());
            temp.data.insert(temp.data.end(), obj.data.begin(), obj.data.end());
        }
        return temp;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyClass& obj);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyClass& obj)
{
    os << obj.size;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < obj.size; ++i)
    {
        os << " " << obj.data[i];
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    MyClass a(5);
    MyClass b(a);
    MyClass c = a + b;
    std::cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `std::vector`, your code can become:

```cpp
class MyClass {
private:
    vector<int> data;
public:
    MyClass(int size) {
        data.resize(size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = rand();
        }
    }
    MyClass operator+(const MyClass& obj) {
        return data.size() + obj.data.size();
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, MyClass& obj);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, MyClass& obj) {
    os << obj.data.size();
    return os;
}
```

Otherwise do not `delete` on an uninitialized pointer. (so either call `new` or set to `nullptr`).
You do not initialize the pointer in the default constructor, so do not call `delete` in the destructor.
Change the default constructor to set `data` to `nullptr`

```cpp
    MyClass() {
        data = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }
```

Also do not copy from an array when you have not initialized the pointer. When you set the `size` variable you are not creating the array. You should create a function called `setSize` and change your code to this:

```cpp
    MyClass(int size) {
        data = nullptr;
        setSize(size);
    }
    void setSize(int size) {
        this->size = size;
        delete[] data;
        data = new int[size];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = rand();
        }
    }
    MyClass operator+(const MyClass& obj) {
        MyClass temp;
        temp.setSize(this->size + obj.size);
        return temp.size;
    }
```

Whenever you need to change the size, you should use the `setSize` function to make sure the array is created as well.

Comment: "*check that data is not nullptr before deleting it*" - you don't need to do that. `delete` can safely be called on a null pointer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did not know that, thank you for that information. I have updated the answer, removing the check for nullptr.